# Algorithm behind custom tool of ArcGIS for Desktop called xyz2grid21?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, convert, dem, lidar

I am a researcher from Romania and I have used  [`xyz2grid21 ArcGIS tool`](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=12876) (by Min-Lang Huang) in order to convert xyz files (LIDAR data) to ASCII and ESRI grid in order to obtain a DTM.

I need to know what algorithm does the XYZ2GRID tool use in order to rasterize the data? Is it using a mean or minimum value or does it interpolate somehow?

Comment: There is nothing about its algorithm in the included help file, so your best option  is to ask the tool's designer directly.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that that tool is an interpolator, but rather a data format conversion tool. That is, it assumes that your data contained in an xyz format is already structured on a regular grid. You will need to import your irregularly spaced LiDAR XYZ points and then use an interpolation routine (e.g. IDW, splining, or kriging) to interpolate the data onto a grid DEM.